# I have a laptop that has 2 display cards. How to make sure the Nvidia one is used?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

First of all, to be honest, I am not sure whether this problem I am facing now is the problem of the OS or the problem of the software itself. Suspecting either of them, I posted a question here.

#### Story

I recently downloaded a PC game (That's Assassin's Creed Odessey, if that helps).
I played this game on both my desktop and my laptop.
It is running perfectly on my desktop, with almost 60 FPS.
The first time I played on my laptop, it is also running perfectly with almost 60 FPS as well.

A few days ago, I played the game on my laptop the second time. Before that, the game has an update and I installed that update.
The game now runs at 2x FPS only.

Of course I thought it was due to the game update. I tried a lot of settings by Googling but none of them helped.

Yesterday evening, I found that Nvidia has a driver update. I installed it and opened the game again, it runs at 60 FPS again! Then I shut down my laptop and went to dinner.
When I came back, turned on my laptop and opened the game again, it ran at 2x FPS again....

#### What I try to achieve

Make the game runs at almost 60 FPS everytime on my laptop.

#### My thoughts

First of all, Since the game has been running at almost 60 FPS on my laptop twice, there are 2 facts that can be certain:

1. The low FPS is not due to hardware weakness. In fact, my laptop has higher performance than my desktop. (Both are i7 and 16GB RAM, but my laptop has a GTX 1050 Ti, my desktop is running a GTX 750 Ti)
2. The low FPS is not due to any game or display setting.

Of course all of these can just be a bug in the game. But I am also suspecting that my Nvidia card is not being used at all. Similar to most laptops in the market, my laptop has 2 display cards, an Intel on-board display and a Nvidia display card. I am highly suspecting that the low FPS is because that only the Intel card is used, but not the Nvidia card.

It can be the OS mis-recognizing the Intel card as the Nvidia card; or it recognized correctly but it is not being used.

I suspected mis-recognizing not from no-where. I tried the performance monitoring tool provided by Windows, and when the game is running at 2x FPS, I saw the `3D` part of the Nvidia GPU is always 100%, and the Intel one is 0%. Given that I think the problem is Nvidia card being un-used, may be the 100% is actually Intel card instead of Nvidia card.

#### What I have tried but not helped

1. Reboot computer

No luck as usual.

2. Reinstalled Nvidia GeForce Experience and all Nvidia drivers.

Just doesn't help.

3. Turn off "Save battery life" in Nvidia GeForce Experience

Doesn't help.

4. Disable Intel display card in Device Manager

Then I tried to open Nvidia settings. Nvidia settings cannot be opened and showed a popup saying something like "No monitor using Nvidia display can be found".
I also tried opening the game. The game can bearly run. I opened performance monitor and see that now I only have one GPU labelled Nvidia, and when the game is running, although I can't even control anything, all dimensions of the GPU usage is 0%. **So even if I disabled Intel card, the Nvidia card is not being used**. (Which is the major reason why I think I may try posting this here in superuser)

So, is there any way that I can force the use of Nvidia display card in this situation? Or, is there something else that I can try?

Comment: Doesn't look like you say what laptop it is but it probably has Nvidia optimus and that would be where the dragons are. Optimus can be a pain.

Comment: @CmosBattery Can I turn it off?

Comment: You can't disable optimus that I know of. You can search for workarounds and see if one works for this laptop. You can also see if the game has a way to force the gpu.

Comment: @Ramhound Hm, I am sorry but I don't get what can't you understand?